# Командная строка и байтовые операции на Си

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Нужно поменять местами два указанных байт числа.
Понимаю, что нужно:

1. попросить ввести пользователя число.
2. затем перевести его в байт число (?), попросить пользователя указать номера байт чисел, которые нужно поменять местами.
3. дальше с помощью цикла и массива поменять местами.
4. выводим новое полученное число

Но я не представляю, как реализовать все, что я поняла... И чтобы число вводилось с командной строки...

Буду благодарна, если объясните!
Есть код, где происходит циклический сдвиг числа вправо. Как организовать цикл из байтов, чтобы от 1 до 8 битов два числа менялись.

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    int main(int args, char** argv[]){
        unsigned b, a;
        int x = atoi(argv[1]), y = atoi(argv[2]);
        unsigned long long num = atoll(argv[3]);
        change(x-1,y-1, num);
    }

    int change(int x, int y, long long z){
        int x1 = z&(long long)(1) << x ? 1:0;
        int y1 = z&(long long)(2) << y ? 1:0;
        z = (z&~((long long)(1)<<x)) | (long long)(y1)<<x;
        z = (z&~((long long)(1)<<y)) | (long long)(x1)<<y;
        printf("\n%lli\n", z);
    }
```

Comment: Приведите пример того, что подаётся на вход, и что должно получиться на выходе.

Comment: Приведите **точную** формулировку вопроса.

Comment: На вход поступает целое число, на выходе тоже должно получиться целое.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если поменять местами байты числа, то получается новое число?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не гнаться за трюками, то пошаговое выделение нужных байтов, сброс соответствующих позиций в 0 и установка новых значений может выглядеть так:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

void change(int x, int y, long long z) {
    //значение байта на позиции x
    long long bx = 0xFF & (z >> (8 * x));
    long long by = 0xFF & (z >> (8 * y));
    //маска содержит нули на позициях x и y
    long long mask = ~(((long long) 0xFF << (8 * x)) | ((long long)0xFF << (8 * y)));
    //обнулили эти позиции
    z &= mask;
    //и заполнили нужными значениями
    z = z | (bx << (8 * y)) | (by << (8 * x));
    printf("%llx\n", z);
}

int main(){
    int x = 2;
    int y = 7;
    unsigned long long num = 0x1133557799BBDDFF;
    printf("%llx\n", num);
    change(x - 1, y - 1, num);
}

1133557799bbddff
11dd557799bb33ff
```

Comment: Что означает эта строчка?                        unsigned long long num = 0x1133557799BBDDFF;

Comment: Я просто задал число UInt64 (unsigned случайно попало, но роли оно не играет) в 16-ричном виде, чтобы легко было видеть отдельные байты, вместо ввода его от пользователя (и x,y тоже)

Comment: Ага, понятно. А здесь т.к. происходит сдвиг, то передаются параметры не просто x,y,  а x-1, y-1? Я правильно понимаю? change(x - 1, y - 1, num);

Comment: Это я взял из вашего кода - такие параметры подразумевают, что задаются номера байтов, начиная с 1 (1-8 для int64), а вот используются c нумерацией с нуля (0-7 для int64)

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснения!