# Командная строка и битовые операции на Си

Tags: c, битовые-операции, командная-строка

Есть код. Как его запустить через командную строку, как это делается вообще. Сама программа должна менять местами два указанных байт числа и брать данные из командной строк и выводить туда же (все ли правильно в коде?)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(int args, char** argv[]){
    unsigned b, a;
    int x = atoi(argv[1]), y = atoi(argv[2]);
    unsigned long long num = atoll(argv[3]);
    change(x-1,y-1, num);
}

void change(int x, int y, long long z) {
    //значение байта на позиции x
    long long bx = 0xFF & (z >> (8 * x));
    long long by = 0xFF & (z >> (8 * y));
    //маска содержит нули на позициях x и y
    long long mask = ~(((long long) 0xFF << (8 * x)) | ((long long)0xFF << (8 * y)));
    //обнулили эти позиции
    z &= mask;
    //и заполнили нужными значениями
    z = z | (bx << (8 * y)) | (by << (8 * x));
    printf("%llx\n", z);
}
```

Comment: "_все ли правильно в коде?_" - как может быть "все правильно" если код элементарно не компилируется? Вы добейтесь сначала чтобы он хотя бы компилировался без ошибок. Про функцию `change` вам компилятор ничего не сообщает?

Comment: @Алия Гафурова В [том вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/966216/Командная-строка-и-битовые-операции-на-Си) я дал ответ, проверив его на работоспособность в VS в режиме C++. Что именно у вас не получается? unsigned уберите.

Comment: я разобралась, как вводить данные через командную строку. 
  я ввожу числа через пробел: 2 5 15, где 2 и 5 это номера байт числа, которые нужно поменять, а 15 - само число.  
   в итоге выводит: f.    
  т.е. он поменял байты числа, и число не изменилос?

Comment: Он поменял, только в числе 15 второй и пятый байты нулевые ;) Вы байты с битами не путаете?

Comment: в 1 байте = 8 бит
число 15 = f в 16-ричной системе
а f это один байт или один бит
вот я знаю, что число 1100 0100 1000 0001 например, тут 2 байта
а в числе f, как вот это все (

Comment: А как мне еще определить позицию самой старшей единицы в битовом представлении введенного мною числа?

Comment: число, представленное в бинарном виде как 1100 0100 1000 0001, равно 0xс481 или 50305dec. Один байт соответствует 8 битам, двум шестнадцатиричным цифрам. Да, в этом числе первый и второй байты ненулевые. Чтобы менять **байты** с большими номерами, вы должны обязать пользователя ввести длинное число (8-9 цифр для int32, 17-18 цифр для int64) - подобно тому числу, что я использовал в [прошлой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/965234). Поэтому я и засомневался -  байты ли Вам нужно менять. Точное задание Вы так и не привели, только свою интерпретацию

Comment: Это уже вторая часть задания, большое-пребольшое спасибо за все объяснения!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как мне еще определить позицию самой старшей единицы в битовом
>   представлении ?

Приблизительно так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
  Определяет позицию самой левой единицы в двоичном представлении числа.

  n - Проверяемое число

  return:
    0...31 - Позиция самой левой обнаруженной единички
    -1 Число равно 0
*/ 

int left_one_position(int n) {
    int j;

    for(j=31; j>=0; j--) {
        if (n & 0x80000000) return j;
        n = n<<1;
    }
    return -1;
}

/*
  Главная функция программа
*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int test_val;
    int position;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Неверные параметры командной строки\n");
        return -1;
    }

    test_val = atoi(argv[1]);
    position = left_one_position(test_val);

    printf("В слове %08x самая левая единица в позиции %5d\n", test_val, position);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!